# randomForest: Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to use `randomForest` for unsupervised classification. According to the tech specification of the package, the simple unsupervised case is defined this way:

```
set.seed(17)
iris.urf <- randomForest(iris[, -5])
MDSplot(iris.urf, iris$Species)
```

However, when I apply the same code to my data, I receive this error:

> Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
>
> In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) : row.names NOT
>   used

```
dt <- data.frame(currentData[,1:ncol(currentData)-1])
names(dt) <- paste0('X', 1:ncol(dt))
g = randomForest(data=dt)
```

Comment: remove the `data=` , (ie `g = randomForest(dt)`). The `?randomForest` help suggests you use the `data=` only when using the `formula` notation

Comment: @user20650 It oddly worked for me as well, even if I was using the formula notation! Why don't you write it as answer?

Comment: note that even if you name the data= and formula= arguments, formula needs to come first in the randomForest function for it to work. it makes no sense, I know, but that's what's happening to me at the moment.