# Random Forest error - Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, random-forest

I am having this issue with random forest throwing an error.

I have this dataframe which contains tweet data that is already in a matrix form with a sentiment column which I am trying to predict.

```
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  2155 variables:
 $ anoth                          : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cancel                         : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ flight                         : num  2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ hold                           : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hour                           : num  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ive                            : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

This is my randomForest that is throwing error.

```
model_rf <- randomForest(data = dtm.df[train,], 
                         formula = as.factor(sentiment) ~ .,
                         importance = T, do.trace = F)
```

my sentiment column is basically a list of values positive and negative

```
Factor w/ 2 levels "negative","positive": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

[1] negative negative negative negative negative negative negative negative
   [9] negative negative negative negative negative negative negative negative
```

The error I get is

```
Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this. I am simply stuck

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
dtm.df$sentiment <- as.factor(dtm.df$sentiment)
model_rf <- randomForest(formula = sentiment ~ .,
                         data = dtm.df[train,], 
                         importance = T, 
                         do.trace = F)
```

Comment: for future references, don'r coerce any thing in the model formula itself it doesn't work untill now

Comment: Thank you @Ayush, that's a lesson learned. I have another issue that came up but I will post that as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment to a similar question ([randomForest: Error in nrow(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28034188/10405322)) the formula argument must always go first for the randomForest function. Some of us instinctually put the data argument first, which works most of the time in R but will result in this error specifically for randomForest. After some fiddling around, I've found that the order of the other arguments does not seem to matter.

@ayush-nigam's answer does this function-first move in the code, but they do not explain this detail, which may be the issue for future users stumbling upon this question.